# Java: Array list of objects & getting values/properties of automatically created checkboxes

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList` of Strings that automatically generates a list of check-boxes (of varying count) in a popup window. I currently have two problems with the below code:

- `Object[] params` doesn't work because it requires me to know the size of the ArrayList `ar` in advance, and I havent figured out to get an arraylist of objects to work with my code. How can I fix this? I tried creating an arraylist of objects, but I could only get it to display nonsensical text.
- How can I get the values/text of each checkbox and it's respective isSelected() state?

Below is my code:

```
String message = "The selected servers will be shutdown.";
Object[] params = {message, null, null, null, null, null};

ArrayList<String> ar = GetSet.getStopCommand(); // Example array: ./Stopplm11.sh|./Stopplm12.sh|./Stopplm14.sh|./Stopplm15.sh

for(int i=0; i< ar.size(); i++){
    JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();
    checkbox.setText(ar.get(i).toString());
    checkbox.setSelected(true);
    params[i+1]= checkbox;
}

int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(btnShutdownServer, params, "Shutdown Servers", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

if (n == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
    // DO STUFF
    //boolean buttonIsSelected= checkbox.isSelected();
}else{
    // user cancelled
}
```

An image, for those who like images:

[image: Image for those who like images]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it an ArrayList of JCheckBox:

```
ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkboxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox>();
```

Then you can do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++)
{
    JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();
    checkbox.setText(ar.get(i).toString());
    checkbox.setSelected(true);

    // add the checkbox to the ArrayList
    checkboxes.add(checkbox);
}
```

Finally, to check the state of all checkboxes in your if condition, you can simply do:

```
if (n == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION){
    // DO STUFF
    //boolean buttonIsSelected= checkbox.isSelected();

    // loop through all checkboxes in the ArrayList
    for (JCheckBox checkbox : checkboxes)
    {
        // current one is selected
        boolean buttonIsSelected = checkbox.isSelected();
    }

    // rest of code in if condition
}
```

Comment: Can I add the checkboxes to "params" like below, so that I only have to create one object to include in "params" instead of "x" objects. -----

Object[] params = {message, checkboxes};

Comment: You can do that if you like, but it would probably be better to create a simple class that can hold onto a String message and an ArrayList<JCheckBox> checkboxes. Then you can have getters and setters for the class. You may want to add more things to the class later on. It's more flexible and you don't have to worry about getting a ClassCastException when getting things from the class as you would with the Object []

Comment: Your code fixed my first issue. Thanks :) One last thing... when I add the checkboxes to the "params", I still get the wrong result. How can I make it display the objects properly? I posted an image at the bottom of my original post of the current result.

Comment: You are getting those "weird" strings because you are either directly or indirectly toString'ing the JCheckBox's in the ArrayList. Instead, you should access the text of each JCheckBox with `checkbox.getText()`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing `params` inside of an array, store those parameters within an `ArrayList`, as such:

```
ArrayList<Object> params = new ArrayList<Object>();
params.add("The selected servers will be shutdown.");

for(int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++)
{
    JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox();
    checkbox.setText(ar.get(i).toString());
    checkbox.setSelected(true);
    params.add(checkbox);
}
```

Then, make `params` an array:

```
Object[] realParams = new Object(params.size());
realParams = params.toArray(realParams);
```

And then continue the rest of the code as you would.